# Get reference to struct member

Tags: python, ctypes

I have the following struct:

```
import ctypes as c
class sigaction_t(c.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("sa_handler", c.c_void_p),
        ("sa_sigaction", c.c_void_p),
        ("sa_mask", c.c_int),
        ("sa_flags", c.c_int),
        ("sa_restorer", c.c_void_p),
    ]
```

How do I get a reference for a member of this struct? Below seems not to be working for `sa_mask`...

```
lib = c.cdll.LoadLibrary("libc.so.6")
sa = sigaction_t()
lib.sigemptyset(c.byref(sa.sa_mask)) #not working
```

> TypeError: byref() argument must be a ctypes instance, not 'int'

I think we can say that `sigemptyset` expects a `c.POINTER(c.c_int)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sa.sa_mask`, when accessed, returns a Python `int` not a `ctypes.c_int` so can't be taken by reference.  There are a number of ways to address this

1. Suppress the automatic conversion of a `c_int` return value to a Python `int`.  Derived classes will return a `c_int` object and its `.value` can be requested to retrieve the Python `int`:

```py
import ctypes as c

class raw_c_int(c.c_int): pass  # Derived classes suppress the conversion

class sigaction_t(c.Structure):
    _fields_ = (("sa_handler", c.c_void_p),
                ("sa_sigaction", c.c_void_p),
                ("sa_mask", raw_c_int),  # use derived class
                ("sa_flags", c.c_int),
                ("sa_restorer", c.c_void_p))

sa = sigaction_t()
lib.sigemptyset(c.byref(sa.sa_mask))
print(sa.sa_mask.value)
```

2. Introduce a temporary variable:

```py
sa = sigaction_t()
mask = c.c_int()
lib.sigemptyset(c.byref(mask)))
sa.sa_mask = mask
```

3. Compute the offset of the member using the optional second parameter of `byref`.  This may require a cast depending on your `sigemptyset.argtypes` definition, as the returned reference unfortunately still has type `POINTER(sigaction_t)`:

```py
sa = sigaction_t()
lib.sigemptyset(c.byref(sa, sigaction_t.sa_mask.offset))

# or

sa = sigaction_t()
lib.sigemptyset(c.cast(c.byref(sa, sigaction_t.sa_mask.offset), c.POINTER(c.c_int)))
print(sa.sa_mask.value)
```